# Como usar Data Tables - footer callback

Tags: php, datatables

hola a todos estoy queriendo usar el footer call back de datatables, mire mucho pero por los diferentes tutoriales pero no logre solucionar mi problema. Entonces Como siempre toca recurrir a la sabiduria del grupo..
Este es el ejemplo de la pagina, pero no consigo q funcione, mude el nombre de mi tabla a example para q pueda correr el plugin y solo me aparece la la tabla dividida en paginas la opcion de buscar y la opcion de mostrar cuantos registros quiero tener x pagina, pero la suma q es lo q necesito no aparece.

Alguien tiene experiencia con esto?? - Desde ya muchas Gracias!!

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 5 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
            '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
        );
    }
} );
```

} );

**Este es mi Html**

```
<div class="box box-solid">
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>movimientos/Ventas/add_funcion" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat"><span class="fa fa-plus "></span> Nueva Venta </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr><!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered btn-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Nombre Cliente:</th>
                          <th>Tipo Comprobante:</th>
                          <th>Numero de comprobante:</th>
                          <th>Fecha:</th>
                          <th>Total:</th>
                          <th>Opciones:</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php if (!empty($ventas)):?>
                        <?php foreach($ventas as $venta):?>
                          <tr>
                            <td> <?php echo $venta->id_ventas;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $venta->nombres_cliente;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $venta->tComprobante;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $venta->numero_comprobante_ventas;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $venta->fecha_ventas;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $venta->total_ventas;?></td>
                            <?php $dataVentas = $venta->id_ventas."*".$venta->nombres_cliente."*".$venta->tComprobante."*".$venta->fecha_ventas."*".$venta->subtotal_ventas."*".$venta->descuento_ventas."*".$venta->iva_ventas."*".$venta->total_ventas;?>
                            <td> <div class ="btn-group">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-view-ventas" data-toggle="modal" 
                                      data-target="#modal-default" value="<?php echo $venta->id_ventas;?>">
                                      <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                                  </button>
                          </tr>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                      <?php endif;?>        
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: @alanfcm gracias x tu comentario, amigo!! ahora lo agregue..

Comment: fijate que en javascript agregas otro ID distinto al de el table en html ...$('#example')..... deberia ser ...$('#example2')

Comment: si, ya lo había cambiado pero igual no funciona me agrega las demás características del datatable pero el footer callback no hace.. leí por ahí q tiene q tener la etiqueta <tfoot> la tablas alguna experiencia?? yo lo agregue después del <tbody> pero sigo sin nada..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te hace falta agregar un `<tfoot>` a tu tabla, de otra forma el `footerCallback` no funciona.  Quedaria asi:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 5 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
            '$'+pageTotal
        );
    }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></link>

<div class="box box-solid">
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>movimientos/Ventas/add_funcion" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat"><span class="fa fa-plus "></span> Nueva Venta </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr><!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered btn-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Nombre Cliente:</th>
                          <th>Tipo Comprobante:</th>
                          <th>Numero de comprobante:</th>
                          <th>Fecha:</th>
                          <th>Total:</th>
                          <th>Opciones:</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>                      
                          <tr>
                            <td> 1</td>
                            <td> juan</td>
                            <td> recibo</td>
                            <td> 1</td>
                            <td> 2/27</td>
                            <td> 100</td>                            
                            <td> <div class ="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-view-ventas" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>    
                          <tr>
                            <td> 1</td>
                            <td> juan</td>
                            <td> recibo</td>
                            <td> 1</td>
                            <td> 2/27</td>
                            <td> 100</td>                            
                            <td> <div class ="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-view-ventas" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>    
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
```

Comment: jajaja!!! que grande!!!! llevaba 3 dias atascado!!! Gracias!!